Trick taking game for 2 players with 2 rows of 5 cards per player
I am looking for the real name of the card game I was playing with my father 30 years ago. He was calling it "Peseta", but I searched for this name and couldn't find even just one record of a card game with this name, so I am now unsure if I remember correctly.

Deal: the dealer deals 5 closed cards for each player. Then he puts 5 faceup cards, on top of the facedown cards.
Trump choice: the non-dealer pick the trump suit, based on his cards.


And after the trump chosen, dealer proceeds with putting 5 cards on top of his closed cards, and proceeds with doing the same by adding another 5-row of open-closed cards. Then each player gets a hand of 6 cards. As below:


Play: The non-dealer plays first, and the dealer either have to play a bigger card, or if he doesn't have it he can play a trump to take the turn. If he doesn't have a bigger card or a trump, he have to give a card of himself.

Strategy: The trick of the game is to bleed the opponent by consuming his trumps, putting him in disadvantageous positions as he will play stronger trumps for weak cards etc.


Is there anyone else familiar with this game?

Don't stuff the tags with things that don't apply. Stratego is a board game, not a card game so it's definitely not connected at all.

"closed" --> "face-down" and "open" --> "face-up"

@Andrew It was Chatgpt's idea, sorry if its not proper.

@Pecheneg we don't allow ai on answers, i dont think thr stance is as strict on questions but still, a big part of the reason is how often ai hallucinations happen, or its just plain wrong.

Rule #2478 of S.E: never mention GPT.

This reminds me a lot of Officers' Skat, but there are differences:
Officers' Skat is played with a 32 card deck, so each player only has 4 (x2 x2) cards before them and no additional hand cards.

Thanks for the answer, sadly this is definitely 52 card game.
